# My firebird query plan does not use correct index

Tags: sql, database, firebird, interbase

I have a problem with indexes in my firebird query.

Below is my query.

```
SELECT a.objid,
       b.running_qty,
       b.running_qty2,
       b.running_totalcost,
       b.running_lastcost
FROM mm_itrghd a,
     mm_itrgdt b
WHERE (a.objid = b.header_id)
AND   (b.item_id = 1200)
AND   (b.wh_id = 1)
AND   ((a.postdate < '2010-09-05 00:00:00')  OR ((a.postdate = '2010-09-05 00:00:00') AND (a.objid < 50000)))
ORDER BY a.postdate desc,
         a.objid desc,
         b.calctyp desc,
         b.objid desc
```

As you see, in order by section, we use desc. I have an descending index, but my query plan does not use it.
It only use index Table A (a.objid) and Table B (b.item_id, b.wh_id)
Is there something i missed? What index do you think should i create?

Index for Table A (mm_itrghd)

(TR_CODE, DOC_ID) Ascending
(OBJID) Ascending
(TR_CODE) Ascending
(POSTDATE) Ascending
(POSTDATE, OBJID) Ascending
(POSTDATE, OBJID) Descending

Index for Table B (mm_itrgdt)

(HEADER_ID) Ascending
(ITEM_ID) Ascending
(WH_ID) Ascending
(LOT_NO) Ascending
(SERIAL_NO, ITEM_ID) Ascending
(HEADER_ID, ITEM_ID, WH_ID, SERIAL_NO, LOT_NO) Ascending
(HEADER_ID, ITEM_ID, WH_ID) Ascending
(CALCTYP, OBJID) Ascending
(ITEM_ID, WH_ID) Ascending
(CALCTYP, OBJID, ITEM_ID, WH_ID) Ascending
(CALCTYP, OBJID) Descending
(OBJID, ITEM_ID, WH_ID) Descending
(OBJID) Descending

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Reynaldi

Comment: I know it sounds frivolous, but could you please reformat your SQL so it is more readable (indent it so it is shown as "code"). Also, please clarify what the index notation that you used means - it is not clear to me why you have some fields grouped and some not (I'm no Firebird expert, so excuse me if I'm asking something obvious). Or better yet use standard CREATE INDEX syntax.

Comment: Do you use tools like IBExpert or Database Workbench ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all update indices statistics because Firebird relay on it when choosing what index to use and what not. Either do backup-restore cycle for database or execute following code:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE IDX VARCHAR(31);
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT rdb$index_name FROM rdb$indices
    WHERE NOT rdb$index_name LIKE 'RDB$%'
    INTO :idx
  DO BEGIN
    EXECUTE STATEMENT 'update statistics ' || :idx
    WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION; 
  END
END
```

Check the query plan after that. If index is not used it is because Firebird thinks that its usage will do more harm then help. You can either specify plan for query manually or try to rewrite it.

In your case you can get rid of OR condition using UNION operator:

```
select 
  a.postdate, 
  a.objid, 
  b.calctyp, 
  b.objid,
  b.running_qty, 
  b.running_qty2, 
  b.running_totalcost, 
  b.running_lastcost 
from 
  mm_itrghd a join mm_itrgdt b 
    on a.objid=b.header_id 
where 
  (b.item_id=1200)
  and (b.wh_id=1) 
  and (a.postdate<'2010-09-05 00:00:00') 

union all

select 
  a.postdate, 
  a.objid, 
  b.calctyp, 
  b.objid,
  b.running_qty, 
  b.running_qty2, 
  b.running_totalcost, 
  b.running_lastcost 
from 
  mm_itrghd a join mm_itrgdt b 
    on a.objid=b.header_id 
where 
  (b.item_id=1200)
  and (b.wh_id=1) 
  and (a.postdate='2010-09-05 00:00:00') 
  and (a.objid<50000)

order by 
  1 desc, 2 desc, 3 desc, 4 desc
```

Comment: That doesn't work and gives you an error `Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 19`. This works: `execute statement 'set statistics index ' || :idx ` which I had from http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq167/

Answer (score 0):

It's just a gut feeling, but try to also select b.objid